# pass FileReference between two flash movies

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, soundcloud-stratus

I have an html page with a flash object that provides video chat using stratus.
I want to enable file sharing from a different UI on the same html page.
I want to use the same stratus connection to send the file.

Is it possible to create a small flash object that will present a browse button and let the user choose a file and then pass the FileReference or file details to the stratus object to send it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two SWFs are on the same page, you should be able to the [LocalConnection](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) API to allow two way communication between the two movies.

I have not directly tried this approach for passing a FileReference object, but it is worth noting that there is a filesize restriction of 40K when using LocalConnection.send() - you may be able to get around this by serialising your FileReference object first and sending it over in chunks.